# How do you create a custom function in IBM Maximo Asset Monitor using Python and is there an SDK?

Tags: maximo

I would like to create my own custom function and add it to the Maximo Asset Monitor Catalog.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom function using Python in IBM Maximo Asset Monitor.   Use the following resources:

1. Knowledge Center documentation includes a tutorial :  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP8H/iot/analytics/tutorials/as_adding_complex_function_tutorial.html
2. Use the Watson IOT Function samples to make more advanced custom functions.  https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/functions/blob/production/iotfunctions/sample.py
3. Fork this github repo: https://github.com/fe01134/functions
4. Watch this step by step video Tutorial https://youtu.be/i5srMxmIOHM
5. Watson IOT Monitor SDKS  and REST APIs for querying data
   db  https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/functions/blob/development/iotfunctions/db.py

Use REST API for Monitor https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/functions/blob/1cf584f30ba259ad98b1ca77684c016df9b21748/iotfunctions/db.py#L773

Queries  https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/functions/blob/development/scripts/test_queries.py